# Is strategic bombing as ineffective as this math suggests?

Tags: world-war-two, bombing

A B 17 has a fuel capacity of 10 tons, and a payload of 1 ton. The 2.5 m tons of bombs dropped thus required 25m tons of fuel. Nazis produced around 5m tons of oil annually domestically.

Does this mean strategic bombing was pretty much a losing proposition? Unless they identified Holocaust trains or such.

Comment: This seems an odd way of evaluating the (in)effectiveness of strategic bombing. Also, are you sure the Germans produced just 5 tons of oil a year?

Comment: I think the most effective way to stop the Holocaust was to defeat Germany.

Comment: Yes, it is as ineffective as your math suggests - if your maths was a valid measure.

Comment: According to a quick glance at https://www.b17texasraiders.org/index.php/texas-raiders/b-17-intel/b-17-specs, a B-17G had a fuel load of 2,780 gallons (at approx 6lbs/gallon) and a bomb of up to 20,000lbs.

Comment: I guess you mean m tons = million tonnes? Better use M tons or Mt (Megatonne) in that case.

Comment: You're comparing 25,000 tons of fuel for the bomber with 5 million tons for Nazis Germany.

Answer (score 4):

It's an interesting way to look at it, but you do state a false equivalence. Not all strategic bombing was aimed at disrupting oil production, and allied production was not equal.

Anything that could possibly help the German war effort was targeted: factories, bridges, harbours, railroads, etc.

Apart from that, a very significant tonnage of bombs (stand by for sources...) was dropped on civilian city centres. This was done to turn the population against the war.

At the end of the day, the allies didn't have to be cost (fuel) efficent about it either. Going by wikipedia, the US produced 833m tonnes of oil during the war, vs Germany's 33m.

Even if that 33m ton was yearly (unbombed) production, that still wouldn't be half of what the US churned out.